# What is the meaning of INTERVAL '0-0' YEAR_MONTH on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, yearmonth

I am trying to understand a MySQL stored procedure but I don't understand the use of `YEAR_MONTH`.
What it means `INTERVAL '0-0'` YEAR_MONTH and `INTERVAL '0-4' YEAR_MONTH`?
What it is used for?

The query on the stored procedure is like this:

```
SELECT remunerations.id_princ,
       remunerations.id_cont,
       customer.t_contraco,
       remunerations.id_ct,
       ABS(SUM(remunerations.item1)) AS item1,
       ABS(SUM(remunerations.item2)) AS item2,
       ABS(SUM(remunerations.item3)) AS item3
FROM customer
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN remunerations ON (customer.id_cont = remunerations.id_cont)
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN contractuals ON (remunerations.id_ct = contractuals.id_ct)
WHERE remunerations.id_princ = var_princ AND
      customer.active_cont = 1 AND
      customer.deactive_princ = 1 AND
      DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(remunerations.anyo_trab, '-', remunerations.mes_trab, '-15'), "%Y-%m-%d") IN ((
              SELECT DATE_SUB(CONCAT(MAX(rm.anyo_trab),'-', MAX(rm.mes_trab),'-15'), INTERVAL '0-0' YEAR_MONTH) AS fecha2
              FROM
                remunerations rm
              WHERE rm.anyo_trab = YEAR (date_sub (NOW(), INTERVAL '0-4' YEAR_MONTH)) AND
                    rm.id_princ = var_princ AND
                    rm.id_cont = remunerations.id_cont
      )) AND
      (remunerations.finiquito_planilla IS NULL OR remunerations.finiquito_planilla >= var_fecha)
GROUP BY remunerations.id_princ,
         remunerations.id_cont,
         customer.elorden,
         remunerations.id_ct;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the DATE_SUB() function is used in SQL to subtract a time/date interval from a date and then returns the date.

so this `date_sub (NOW(), INTERVAL '0-4' YEAR_MONTH)` means that

```
date_sub - function to subtract    
NOW() -  would be the current DATE and TIME
INTERVAL - value to be added or subtracted
'0-4' - corresponds to YEAR=0 & MONTH=4
```

So you can read the expression as subtract 4 months from Current date and time .

You can check this in a simple [Select](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66c474/2) Query

Addionally,also please check this official Doscumentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 1):

That is an argument to DATE_SUB.  Looking at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) for that, it says:

> See the description for DATE_ADD().

And the [documentation there](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) says:

> DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit), DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)

Your unit is YEAR_MONTH, so according to the linked [Temporal Intervals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals), the expression is a number of years and months to subtract, separated by a '-'.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is used to cast value to date data type:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CONCAT(MAX(rm.anyo_trab),'-', MAX(rm.mes_trab),'-15'), 
            INTERVAL '0-0' YEAR_MONTH) AS fecha2
```

As

```
CONCAT(MAX(rm.anyo_trab),'-', MAX(rm.mes_trab),'-15'
```

is definitely a text. Adding `0` literaly does not change the value except implicit conversion. Effectively it is the same as:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(MAX(rm.anyo_trab),'-', MAX(rm.mes_trab),'-15') AS DATE) ...
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9122990bdcb4c957a36987dbd99ba70)**